# utf8 html input tag is not respected after refreshing the page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I'm developping an search form with springMVC, in which I have an input tag and a submit button.
If I write in the input tag:

```
   "Cherché"
```

and I submit. Then, the same data in the input tag will be

```
   "CherchÃ©"
```

Any help please?

Note that:
- I have already this header in the html page:

```
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

- I have specified the coding in springMVC

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/project/data", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
```

Comment: @ashokramcse: same result

Comment: Is it a POST or a GET?

Comment: Also, when I change get --> post, it works correctly
@Maurice Perry add your answer please

Comment: I did: I've noticed that the method is not specified in the @RequestMapping, and the default is GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're submitting form data using the GET method, you must ensure the servlet engine is using UTF-8 to decode the URLs.
With tomcat, it is in the Connector tag of server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```